# Excel VBA Trying to send data from excel workbook to an other

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't been able to find a question that is close enough to what i need or maybe i'm not as good as googling as I thought I was.

Anyway I have an issue where I need to use excel as a database as my place of work doesn't have access.

The way in which this is supposed to work is that in the 'ui' workbook after the user has inputed the data required it needs to take the users employee number from the 'ui' workbook and use that to find them in a list of all employees on the 'database' worksheet then increase a field that indicates that they have completed this specific task one more time.  Then on a different sheet also on the second workbook it needs to record the date completed and also input the users id against this date.

so far I haven't attempted the code for the second part as I am having trouble with the first.  Here is what i have so gotten to so far and it errors at the match function

```
Sub SendToDB()
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim DB As Workbook
    Dim UI As Workbook
    Dim ENo As Long
    Dim CopyFrom As Worksheet
    Set CopyFrom = Worksheets("Checklist")
 
    
    ENo = Range("G45").Value
    Set UI = ThisWorkbook
    Set DB = Workbooks.Open("file location here\database.xlsx", True)
    Dim EmCount As Long
    Dim EmRow As Long
    Dim EmCell As Range

    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    DB.Worksheets("EMLIST").Activate
    
       
    EmRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ENo, Range("AML"), 0)
    
    EmCell = Range("G" & EmRow)
    
    EmCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(EmENo, Range("AML"), 7, False)
    EmCount = EmCount + 1
    
    EmCell.Value = EmCount
    
    DB.Close True
    Set DB = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

AML is a named range on the database spreadsheet which contains all the employee data

Thanks

Comment: Either `Eno` or `AML` have not been found. Since you are probably sure that `ENo` exists, you should focus on `Range("AML")` which is currently being search for in `Worksheets("EMLIST")` since you haven't qualified it. Check which scope the named range is of: worksheet or workbook. To do this e.g. open the `Name Manager` and afterward qualify the range appropriately. Also, `Match` is the easiest used in the 
 `Application.Match` version, which allows you to test the result with `IsError` or `IsNumeric`: `Dim EmRow As Variant: EmRow = Application.Match(...)` : `If IsErorr(EmRow) Then...`.

Comment: ... By qualifying I mean using e.g. `DB.Worksheets("Database").Range("AML")` or using a variable: `Dim rg As Range: Set rg = DB.Worksheets("Database").Range("AML")` and using `rg` in the functions.

Comment: Thank you, there were a few more teething problems but you got me on the right track thank you.